# FIWARE object storage authorization error

Tags: cloud, openstack, fiware

We are experiencing an unexpected problem in the implementation of generic enabler Object Storage GE - FIWARE Implementation prevents us from continuing to work on our project.

We need help in the implementation of OpenStack. We launched base instance, where the module Object Storage is necessary and access to the API endpoint, through which we will be able to manage files. Unfortunately, the module still reports that the user is not authorized to perform the operation, despite correct data for administration authorizing (eg. keystone operations works).

Here are the details of the problem:

```
> Apr 10 00:10:10 hgl01cdn001 account-server: 127.0.0.1 - -
> [09/Apr/2015:22:10:10 +0000] "HEAD
> /sdb1/287/AUTH_e25b32a839764681b21916b7cc8f4b55" 404 -
> "HEADhttp://91.232.102.168:8080/v1/AUTH_e25b32a839764681b21916b7cc8f4b55"
> "txee17503fc75148e681a8e-005526f8c2" "proxy-server 6528" 0.0003 "-"
> 6627 - Apr 10 00:10:10 hgl01cdn001 proxy-server: - -
> 09/Apr/2015/22/10/10 HEAD /v1/AUTH_e25b32a839764681b21916b7cc8f4b55
> HTTP/1.0 204 - Swift - - - - txee17503fc75148e681a8e-005526f8c2 -
> 0.0042 RL - 1428617410.781399012 1428617410.785646915 - Apr 10 00:10:10 hgl01cdn001 proxy-server: Identity server rejected
> authorization Apr 10 00:10:10 hgl01cdn001 proxy-server: Identity
> response: {"error": {"message": "Invalid username or password (Disable
> debug mode to suppress these details.)", "code": 401, "title":
> "Unauthorized"}} Apr 10 00:10:10 hgl01cdn001 proxy-server: Retrying
> validation Apr 10 00:10:11 hgl01cdn001 proxy-server: Identity server
> rejected authorization Apr 10 00:10:11 hgl01cdn001 proxy-server:
> Identity response: {"error": {"message": "Invalid username or password
> (Disable debug mode to suppress these details.)", "code": 401,
> "title": "Unauthorized"}} Apr 10 00:10:11 hgl01cdn001 proxy-server:
> Authorization failed for token
> 
> $ swift stat Account HEAD
> failed:http://91.232.102.168:8080/v1/AUTH_e25b32a839764681b21916b7cc8f4b55
> 401 Unauthorized.
```

Instructions from which we started
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/guides/single-vm.html

The exact link to version we downloaded / installed:

```
git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are using an invalid header to perform your request.

You have to add a header "X-Auth-Token: 
validtokenIdfortenantAUTH_e25b32a839764681b21916b7cc8f4b55"

The token should be requested for the tenant AUTH_e25b32a839764681b21916b7cc8f4b55
if you request a token for another tenantid, your requests to this tenantid, will fail. Obviously, the token should be requested to the keystone associated to the object storage.

Check again.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, we know that the cause of our problems was the fact that Object Storage GE works well only in certain OpenStack instances. Of course, we wrongly assumed that the instance does not matter and we implemented previously familiar to us dev instance.

We managed to install OpenStack Juno with Swift, all is working, thank you for your assistance. The key was help from Kenneth, so thank you very much for this a tip. We can not express the gratitude! :) GE was correctly installed and so far we do not have any communication / authorization problems. We are in the testing phase (containers).

Because we are part of Fiware community, we would like to make this information available to all interested teams before they try to implement the GE.

Links to OpenStack Juno: http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/content/
http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/content/ch_basic_environment.html#basics-packages